# Adding a body class with ACF

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, body-class

I have created a radio button field with ACF so that admin can specify a colour. E.g:

- blue : Blue
- pink : Pink

I'd like this to be output as a class via `<body <?php body_class(); ?>` in header.php. Is this possible?

I'm currently outputting the class in header.php like so:

```
<div id="page" class="site <?php the_field('package_colour',$post->ID); ?>">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hook into the [`body_class`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) filter and add your field there. It might be better to get the ID from [`get_queried_object_id()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object_id/) instead of [`get_the_ID()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID).

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'wpse_20160118__body_class' );

function wpse_20160118__body_class( $classes ) {

    if ( $package_colour = get_field( 'package_colour', get_queried_object_id() ) ) {

        $package_colour  = esc_attr( trim( $package_colour ) );

        $classes[]       = $package_colour;
    }

    return $classes;
}
```

Comment: `the_field` functions output the value, not return. So `get_field()` is better.

Comment: I've added this to functions.php and here's what I'm seeing via the inspector: `<body blueclass="single single-products postid-136">`

Comment: Thanks @KolyaKorobochkin, using `get_field()` fixed the issue :)

Comment: **get_the_ID()** had produced problems for me and wasn’t reliable, your version is foolproof and works just well.